# Hibernate: Ignore properties with special values for insert & update

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I configure Hibernate to ignore properties with some special values for insert & update?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Transient` annotation for your fields (inside the Entity) which need to be ignored as part of persistence.

> This annotation specifies that the property or field is not
>   persistent.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id 
    int id;

    @Transient 
    String ignoreMe;
}
```

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)

Comment: I need to ignore properties, only if property equals to a certain value. Not always.